# C# TCP Socket.Receive issue when reusing socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

preface:

I've been stumped on this for awhile now and am not having much luck finding what I need.
I have a C# (.NET 3.5) Service.  One thread acts as an asynchronous listener for incoming TCP connections.  When data comes in I spawn off a new worker thread to handle the data, and sends an acknowledgement back.

On a second thread in the same service we send commands out, until today it would gather information from the data base, build a new socket, connect then ship the command and I'm using the Socket.Receive to invoke blocking and wait for a response (or until a timeout occurrs).

Everything has been working great until a new client has a need to send data to us so fast (5-10 second intervals) that we can no longer open a new socket to get a command through.  So I started looking into when a command needs to be sent that the "listener" thread has a client connected.  If that client is connected currently use that socket instead of creating a new one.

Issue:
I'm to the point where I can send my command back on the same socket the listener receives, but when the client sends data back as the response it takes twice for the Socket.Receive method to actually fire thinking it received data.  The first time it gets into my listener class, the 2nd time, in my command class where I actually want it to be.

Question:
Is there some option or something I need to do before calling my Socket.Receive method to ensure the data gets to the correct place?

In my listener class I have a list of objects "CSocketPacket"

```
public class CSocketPacket
{
   public CSocketPacket(System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket)
   {
      thisSocket = socket;
      this.IpAddress =
          ((System.Net.IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
   }

   public System.Net.Sockets.Socket thisSocket;
   public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
   public string IpAddress; //Use this to search for the socket
}
```

Then when I send a command I'm creating a new tcp socket object:

```
client = new Socket(
   AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(
   IPAddress.Parse(Strings.Trim(ipAddress)), port);
IPEndPoint LocalIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(
   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SourceIP"]), port);
```

then I'm looking into my listener class list to see if that socket is connected:

```
if (listener.SocketExists(ipAddress)) 
{
   // set the client socket in this class to the 
   // instance of the socket from the listener class
   SocketIndex = listener.FindSocketInList(ipAddress);
   if (SocketIndex != -1)
   {
      // might need to figure out how to avoid copying the socket
      // to a new variable ???
      client = listener.ConnectedSockets[SocketIndex].thisSocket;
      SocketBeingReUsed = true;
   }
}
else
{
   // try to connect to the client
   client.Connect(ep);
}
```

finally I go through my steps of sending and receiving

```
if (client.Connected)
{
   if (client.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectWrite))
   {
      int sentAmount = Send(ref client);
      client.ReceiveTimeout = 90000; //90 seconds
      returnData = ReceiveData(ref client, sentAmount);
   }
}
```

everything works up to the point in my ReceiveData(ref client, sentAmount) method where I call the `Socket.Receive(data, total, Socket.ReceiveBufferSize, SocketFlags.None);` method.

I've been using a tool called Hercules to test sending/receiving packets across two machines on my home network.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I can do to solve this?  I do apologize for such a lengthy question but I want to try to give as much info and not paste my entire project.  I'm up for any suggestions.

*Disclaimer: I wrote this code approx 3 years ago, so I'm pry doing things I shouldn't be I'm sure* :P

Thanks to all who read this.

Sincerely,

Chris

Comment: Why are the clients re-connecting every time they send  you data? Ideally, the socket connection should stay open as long as you're interacting with the client.

Comment: A lot (99%) of the clients are embedded devices that communicate via satellite terminals, or GPRS/CDMA modems. So the satellites may be orbiting which cause them to lose signal, or the device (if attached to a moving truck) may travel out of rage on the cell network (remote locations). Most of the hardware is not designed to reconnect until it's scheduled to send us data again, even though they may have a connection to the respective network. So we do commands to let the customer try to "poll" data off the device if they don't want to wait for scheduled data. Hope this offers more insight.

Comment: OK got that, but I'm lost on another issue: what's going on in your listener class and in your command class? You said: *"The first time it gets into my listener class, the 2nd time, in my command class where I actually want it to be."* What does that mean? Are you receiving on the same socket from two classes?

Comment: @Lirik, yeah that is my overall issue too.  Esentially what is happening is both classes (listener/command) are in a receiving state.  I'm actually in the middle of trying to come up with a solution to this.  In my listener class, I have a method "OnDataReceived" to handle my incoming data for processing.  When that is finished I call another method that lets the socket know to begin receiving data again.  I don't think what I'm going to do is a true solution but more of a work-around, but it seems like I need to disable the event in my listener class when a command gets sent out.  Not ideal

Comment: So that's the problem then: you shouldn't use two threads to read from the same socket. See my answer for more details.

Comment: you're "pry" doing things you shouldn't? you're really going to use "pry" that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so now I'm following along! Given what you've said in the comments above, then the way to solve the problem is to have a single class/thread that reads from the socket (which is the correct way to read from sockets anyway) and then it will coordinate which class gets the data. I think it might work a little like the [Command Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: Yeah I agree with that completely.  I'll have to do some work to get to that point.  Thanks for the info, I'll give that link a good read this afternoon.

Comment: @Chris, the Command Design Pattern might be a little more than you actually need, but the concept is the same. You just need to detect which class is supposed to handle the "message" and pass it along to that class.

Comment: Got it working using your suggestions.  My listener class is now the main data handler when data comes in and I send the data to appropriate classes to handle responses.  I still have a command thread but all it does is send the command out.  No more multiple receives.  Thanks again for the advice!